# Check the condition and run commands in bash

Tags: linux, bash, docker, shell, if-statement

I am need of running series of commands after checking the conditions. I tried this

```
#var1 results in output active or inactive
var1= systemctl is-active docker


#Function for enabling and running the docker service

function run {
echo "Starting Docker service.."
sudo systemctl enable docker
sudo systemctl start docker
mkdir /mnt/new/hello_test
}

# Checking whether the docker service is up or not

if [[ $var1 -eq inactive ]]
        then
        echo "$(run)"
else
        echo "Docker service is  running..." ; touch /mnt/new/testingg;
fi
```

In this script, it is only checking 1st condition. ANy help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `var1=$(systemctl is-active docker)`? And you should probably do the test differently: `if [[ $var1 == inactive ]]` because `-eq` is for numerical comparisons.

Comment: Okay, I'll try that

Comment: @TedLyngmo Tried. Still it's checking only IF part.

Comment: Did you change the comparison too (what KamilCuk has in that answer is even better)

Comment: Oh yes.! worked now!. Changed the comparison. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

> In this script, it is only checking 1st condition

Because `-eq` is for numbers. Both sides `[[ <this> -eq <that> ]]` are converted to numbers. Because they are not numbers but strings `active` and `inactive`, they are interpreted as variable names and because these variables are not defined, both sides are equal zero.

But forget it, just execute the actual command in `if`:

```
run() {
   echo "Starting Docker service.."
   sudo systemctl enable docker
   sudo systemctl start docker
   mkdir /mnt/new/hello_test
}

if ! systemctl is-active -q docker; then
        run
else
        echo "Docker service is  running..."
        touch /mnt/new/testingg;
fi
```

Anyway to compare strings, use `=`:

```
[[ "stringone" = "stringsecond" ]]
# like:
var1=$(systemctl is-active docker)
[[ "$var1" = "inactive" ]]
```

Comment: Just for amusement, note that Perl uses the symbols like `==` for comparing numbers and the alphabetic ones like `-eq` for comparing strings, which is the reverse of the shell convention (with the added caveat that formally the shell uses `=` and not `==` for equality).  Totally tangential to the question.